# Reprocess a Kafka message

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have written custom deserialiser by extending kakfkaavrodeserializer.

When an exception occurs catching that and logging that exception.

I want to deserialize the message with exception again for certain number of attempts for eg. 5 times if it is a specific type of exception like connect exception instead of logging that immediately. After 5 retries only I want to log the exception.

Could you please guide me in achieving this.

Its a plain java project without annotations, spring etc. Below is the custom deserialiser class.

```
public object deserialize (String s, byte[] bytes){

   try{
     return deserialize (bytes);
   } catch(Exception e){

   Log.error(e.getMessage());
   return null;
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what's preventing you from writing a loop? Or why you think the next 5 attempts at the same record wouldn't have the same error?

Comment: Most of the time for the failed messages I am getting connect exception. So want try for 5 times.  What I have to loop. deserialize method?. I want to retry only failed messages.

Comment: Connection exception to the Schema Registry? You should install more than one for high availability and fix your networking problems. If one request doesn't connect, it's unlikely that trying again within the next few seconds will work either and will cause even more load on the registry server